# Access denied in client credentials flow

Tags: spring-security

## What I do:

I am preparing spring boot oauth2 authorization server with two flows:

- `access code` (users)
- `client credentials` (services)

## Problem

When I am using curl to get `access token` with `client credentials` flow:

```
curl --request POST \
   -vv \
  --url 'http://localhost:9000/oauth/token' \
  --header "Authorization: Basic Y2xhc3Nlcy1jYWxlbmRhci1jbGllbnQ6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=client_credentials
```

I am redirected to login page.
In logs I see `access denied`.

## Config

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("classes-calendar-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}password")  // FIXME this accepts no password encoding
                .clientName("classes-calendar-client")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://auth-service:8080/login/oauth2/code/classes-calendar-client")
                .redirectUri("http://auth-service:8080/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope("all")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://oauth2-service:9000")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails service = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("service")
                .password("password")
                .roles("SERVICE")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, service);
    }
}
```

## Logs

```
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$617/0x0000000800fadcb8@2c2a027c, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@118dcbbd, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7d979d34, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@36aa52d2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.ProviderContextFilter@1a47a1e8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6cbe7d4d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@141d3d43, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@73ae0257, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@3d90eeb3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@7650ded6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@1084f78c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@3df1a1ac, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@2b38b1f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@58606c91, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@403c3a01, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@350ec690, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@16a35bd, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@ba17be6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@49cb1baf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3679d92e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3456558, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@261db982, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@18a25bbd, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@77f905e3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@1192b58e, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@f5ce0bb]] (1/2)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3e4e8fdf, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6a1d6ef2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7f973a14, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2c991465, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2740e316, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1cfc2538, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@42cc183e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3451f01d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2721044, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@76130a29, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@124d02b2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@205df5dc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5fef2aac, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5b5a4aed, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@53e76c11]] (2/2)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth/token
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9000/oauth/token
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$617/0x0000000800fadcb8@2c2a027c, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@118dcbbd, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7d979d34, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@36aa52d2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.ProviderContextFilter@1a47a1e8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6cbe7d4d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@141d3d43, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@73ae0257, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@3d90eeb3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@7650ded6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@1084f78c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@3df1a1ac, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@2b38b1f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@58606c91, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@403c3a01, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@350ec690, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@16a35bd, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@ba17be6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@49cb1baf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3679d92e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3456558, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@261db982, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@18a25bbd, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@77f905e3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@1192b58e, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@f5ce0bb]] (1/2)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3e4e8fdf, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6a1d6ef2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7f973a14, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2c991465, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2740e316, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1cfc2538, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@42cc183e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3451f01d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2721044, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@76130a29, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@124d02b2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@205df5dc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5fef2aac, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5b5a4aed, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@53e76c11]] (2/2)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 50C9343D22CA6AC093145811E89DF30A using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (8/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (9/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (10/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : No saved request
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (11/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (12/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=50C9343D22CA6AC093145811E89DF30A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (13/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (14/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (15/15)
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=50C9343D22CA6AC093145811E89DF30A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5d342959], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=50C9343D22CA6AC093145811E89DF30A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ...]

--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Did not save request since it did not match [And [Ant [pattern='/**', GET], Not [Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.*']], Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@1e512e7c, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@29debe11, matchingMediaTypes=[multipart/form-data], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@4cc94ca2, matchingMediaTypes=[text/event-stream], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]]]
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/login
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
--- [nio-9000-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
```

## Question

What I need to do to make it work?

Comment: If you get 403 (access denied), then you have to allow access to the endpoint. But you already did it. So show your logs, maybe there is some more information about the reason.

Comment: I added logs to question.

Comment: You logs are clear: *Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9000/oauth/token*. You have to load your login page and extract the CSRF token. Then you have to add the CSRF token to your cURL command. For testing, you could also disable CSRF support.

Comment: Actually, csrf protection is disabled for authorization server endpoints. In this case, it looks as though you're using the wrong URL. I'll try and add a few details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the response to [`localhost:9000/.well-known/openid-configuration`](http://localhost:9000/.well-known/openid-configuration). You should see the `token_endpoint` URL is `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token`.

**Note:** Since you've specified `.issuer("http://oauth2-service:9000")` in your `ProviderSettings`, it may reflect `http://oauth2-service:9000/oauth2/token` instead. If you omit this setting, it will detect the base url from the request automatically.

Make sure your request uses `/oauth2/token` instead. Also, make sure you include `client_id=classes-calendar-client` in your request, as I believe that is a required parameter for a `client_credentials` token request.